# html textbox to preserve line breaks

Tags: html, newline

I was wondering if there is a possibility to make a html text input (textbox) to preserve new lines, because when I paste a formatted text into a textbox, the text automatically looses new lines. I guess this is a normal/standard behaviour of this control, but is there any way to prevent this from happening, or the only option is to use TextArea Control.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`<textarea wrap='hard'>Perserve
line breaks</textarea>`